Extension of meromorphic distribution
Let $W$ be a topological vector space (e.g. Frechet) with a dense subspace $V$. Let $D_s$ be a distribution on $V$ that is meromorphic in $s\in\mathbb C$ and extends continuously to $W$ with respect to a given family of seminorms. Then is it true that the extension of $D_s$ to $W$ is also meromorphic and has singularities at most those of $D_s|_V$?
My reasoning is the following, but it feels suspicious for some reason: Let $w\in W$,and let $(v_n)$ be a sequence in $V$ converging to $w$. For any $\epsilon >0$, by continuity, since $||D_s(v_n) − D_s(w)|| < \epsilon$ for $v_n$ close to $w$, it follows that $D_s(w)$ must be holomorphic whenever $D_s(v_n)$ is.
Any related references would be appreciated also.

What do you mean by "distribution on a topological vector space" (i.e., what are the test functions if $W$ has infinite dimension, and is therefore not locally-compact)?

I'm thinking of $V$ as something like $C_c^\infty(G)$ where $G$ is a nice locally compact group, for example.
